# URlencode with php dynamic drop downs

Tags: php, sql, get, encode

I'm working to try and establish a "safe" dynamic form using php/jquery. I am trying to figure out how to encode a query result in the URL, but also being able to display the query correctly in the browser. Ive tried wrapping a urlencode around the data in each of the for loops but it outputs the encoded data and disables the ability to populate the second drop down.

```
        <!-- Populate First Dropdown -->
        <select id="first-choice" name="cardset">
            <?php foreach ($data as $row): ?>
                <option><?=htmlentities($row["name"])?></option>
            <?php endforeach ?>
        </select>

<br />
        <!-- Populate Second Dropdown -->
        <select id="second-choice" name="card">
            <option>Please choose from above</option>
        </select>
        <!-- Jquery to Populate second and Produce image -->
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script language=JavaScript >
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $("#first-choice").change(function() {
                    $.get("getter.php", { choice: $(this).val() }, function(data) {
                        $("#second-choice").html(data);
                    });
                });


                    $("#second-choice").change(function() {
                    var first = $("#first-choice").val();
                    var sec = $(this).val();
                    $("#image-swap").attr("src", (first !== "" &&  + sec !== "") ? "pics/" + first + "/" + sec + ".jpg" : "");
                    });
                });
        </script>
```

Here is the getter.php file I use to populate second drop down using above jquery:

```
$choice = $_GET['choice'];

    $sth = $db->prepare("SELECT code FROM sets WHERE name='$choice'");
    $sth->execute();
    $choicecode = $sth->fetchColumn();

    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM cards WHERE code='$choicecode'");
    $stmt->execute();
    $data2 = $stmt->fetchAll();
?>
<?php foreach ($data2 as $row): ?>
    <option><?=$row["cardname"]?></option>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Basically I want to encode the data that goes in the drop downs because they contain spaces and apostrophes. How can I still do this while at the same time output them correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`urlencode` should be used when you're constructing the query parameters in a URL. When you're putting text into HTML, you should use `htmlentities`. Also, use the ID column as the value in your options.

```
<?php foreach ($data as $row): ?>
    <option value="<?=$row["id"]?>"><?= htmlentities($row["name"]) ?></option>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Also, you should use parametrized queries to prevent SQL injection and avoid other problems when constructing the query if it contains special characters:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM cards 
                      WHERE code = (SELECT code FROM sets WHERE id = :id)");
$stmt->execute(array(':id' => $_GET['choice']));
$data2 = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this all works but I used htmlentities and I still return %20 for spaces in the address: first-choice comes out as: Arena%20League and second-choice: Gaea's%20Blessing. The first option is being used as a query parameter when I use GET in the second php file to populate second drop down.

Comment: How are you seeing that? It should be decoded automatically when the parameters are put into `$_GET`.

Comment: I have another jquery function that produces an image based on second selection's name, it shows the path as http://localhost/~myname/mysite/pics/Archenemy%20%22Schemes%22/Gaea's%20Blessing.jpg

Comment: It really sounds to me like you put the encoding in your DB.

Comment: In the DB is the normal non-encoded names. I just verified. for example i see Archenemy Schemes and Gaea's Blessing.

Comment: You keep mentioning jquery, but I don't see any use of it in your question. You're populating everything in PHP. Am I missing something?

Comment: I should've shown that in initial post, I have now edited post to show entirety.

Comment: You can avoid all this confusion by putting an `ID` column in your tables, and using this in the `value` attribute of the options, rather than matching on the strings.

Comment: I can't see any reason why the percent characters are showing up literally. jQuery encodes the parameter in `$.get`, but PHP decodes it when filling in `$_GET`.

Comment: What do you see when you `View Source`, do you see the percents?

Comment: The table values in my DB do have IDs. The first dd are Card Sets, with ID, NAME, CODE. The second dd is of Cards in the Set. ID, CNAME, SETCODE. CODE=SETCODE. I am unable to figure out a different way of displaying the drop downs

Comment: I've updated my answer to show how to use the ID in the first drop-down. The second should be similar.

Comment: Shouldn't I be using Code as value, since that is the connection between the Sets and cards?

Comment: And no, I only see the percents when copy and paste the image address, because the images won't show if there are spaces in the name

Comment: Percents are normal in the image URL, since spaces aren't allowed there. That's the browser encoding the URL properly.

Comment: Got it, I appreciate you working with a Noob. Since I am now comparing by value and not string, how should I change the jquery line:  $.get("getter.php", { choice: $(this).val() }, function(data) ...Im assuming the choice needs to indicate the value="code" instead of the string I am using

Comment: `$(this).val()` will get the value from the `value=ID` attribute. It only falls back on the string if there's no value attribute.

Comment: Make sure your first `SELECT` query returns the `id` column. You didn't show that part of the code, I just assumed it did. Also, case is sigificant. If the name of the column is `ID`, then you need `$row['ID']`